# Video creation from series of images?

Tags: android

How to create the video from series of png images. Is it possible in android can any body suggest me to do that?

Comment: You want to do it programmatically or via an app?

Comment: i want to do it programatically in my case i am taking the screen shots i want to convert these screen shots as video file

Comment: iam also facing same problem.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839777/878126

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to generate a video (not exactly video, but like video) through the series of images.
There is what you call "mpeg stream" which consists of the JPEG images in the multipart fashion that you read from a source (remote basically) and continuously updating the UI on the screen by parsing it nad fetching the binary content and converting it to objects of bitmap.
If you are having the images locally, you can simply instanciate the bitmap objects and the place them periodically on the UI / ImageView on screen.
What you needs to care about is that the updating frequency should be such that user sees it like a video is playing.
If you have to make a short period video (some animation kinda video) with the help of the already made frames/images, you can follow the link
http://android-support-akkilis.blogspot.com/2011/12/animation-drawbles-in-android.html 
Hope this helps

Comment: but here i must create the video file becouse after creation of video i need to upload that video to facebook.