# How to Make MP4 file from Images?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me how to combine images and generate a mp4 file in android and store the video file in sdCard?

Comment: you could give ffmpeg a chance

Comment: But it a ndk library i wish to do all these things using sdk only

Comment: What is your minimum API level requirement?

Comment: i think you are finding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images

Comment: You can use jcodec `SequenceEncoder` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520705/using-jcodec-sequenceencoder/20630238#20630238

Comment: *Minimum 2.3 icecreamSandwich* -> ICS is version 4.0, 2.3 was Gingerbread, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images :- Go through to this link

Comment: Here's one solution I've got: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839777/878126

Answer (score 9):

Please check the below code

Make one file **FfmpegController.java**

```
public class FfmpegController {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static Utility mUtility;
    private static String mFfmpegBinaryPath;

    public FfmpegController(Context context) {

        mContext = context;

        mUtility = new Utility(context);

        initFfmpeg();
    }

    private void initFfmpeg()
    {
        /*
        Save the ffmpeg binary to app internal storage, so we can use it by executing java runtime command.
         */

        mFfmpegBinaryPath = mContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/ffmpeg";

        if (Utility.isFileExsisted(mFfmpegBinaryPath))
            return;

        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ffmpeg);

        mUtility.saveFileToAppInternalStorage(inputStream, "ffmpeg");

        Utility.excuteCommand(CommandHelper.commandChangeFilePermissionForExecuting(mFfmpegBinaryPath));
    }

    public void convertImageToVideo(String inputImgPath)
    {
        /*
        Delete previous video.
         */

        Log.e("Image Parth", "inputImgPath - "+inputImgPath);

        if (Utility.isFileExsisted(pathOuputVideo()))
            Utility.deleteFileAtPath(pathOuputVideo());

        /*
        Save the command into a shell script.
         */

        saveShellCommandImg2VideoToAppDir(inputImgPath);

        Utility.excuteCommand("sh" + " " + pathShellScriptImg2Video());
    }

    public String pathOuputVideo()
    {
        return mUtility.getPathOfAppInternalStorage() + "/out.mp4";
    }

    private String pathShellScriptImg2Video()
    {
        return mUtility.getPathOfAppInternalStorage() + "/img2video.sh";
    }

    private void saveShellCommandImg2VideoToAppDir(String inputImgPath)
    {
        String command = CommandHelper.commandConvertImgToVideo(mFfmpegBinaryPath, inputImgPath, pathOuputVideo());

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());

        mUtility.saveFileToAppInternalStorage(is, "img2video.sh");
    }
}
```

Make another Java file **Utility.java**

```
public class Utility {

    private final static String TAG = Utility.class.getName();
    private static Context mContext;

    public Utility(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static String excuteCommand(String command)
    {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "execute command : " + command);

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            reader.close();

            process.waitFor();

            Log.d(TAG, "command result: " + output.toString());

            return output.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return "";
    }

    public String getPathOfAppInternalStorage()
    {
        return mContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public void saveFileToAppInternalStorage(InputStream inputStream, String fileName)
    {
        File file = new File(getPathOfAppInternalStorage() + "/" + fileName);
        if (file.exists())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "SaveRawToAppDir Delete Exsisted File");
            file.delete();
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isFileExsisted(String filePath)
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return file.exists();
    }

    public static void deleteFileAtPath(String filePath)
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Make another file **CommandHelper.java**

```
public class CommandHelper {
    public static String commandConvertImgToVideo(String ffmpegBinaryPath, String inputImgPath, String outputVideoPath) {
        Log.e("ffmpegBinaryPath", "ffmpegBinaryPath - "+ffmpegBinaryPath);
        Log.e("inputImgPath", "inputImgPath - "+inputImgPath);
        Log.e("outputVideoPath", "outputVideoPath - "+outputVideoPath);

        return ffmpegBinaryPath + " -r 1/1 -i " + inputImgPath + " -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x480 " + outputVideoPath;
    }

    public static String commandChangeFilePermissionForExecuting(String filePath) {
        return "chmod 777 " + filePath;
    }
}
```

When you want to execute code and make images to video please use below code.

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {

         ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            /* mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.this);

             mProgressDialog.setMessage("Converting...");

             mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

             mProgressDialog.show();*/

             Log.e("Video Process Start", "======================== Video Process Start ======================================");
         }

         @Override
         protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

            saveInputImgToAppInternalStorage();
/*           for(int i = 1; i<11 ; i++){
             mFfmpegController.convertImageToVideo(mUtility.getPathOfAppInternalStorage() + "/" + "Img"+i+".jpg");
             }
*/

            mFfmpegController.convertImageToVideo(mUtility.getPathOfAppInternalStorage() + "/" + "img%05d.jpg");
             return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
             Log.e("Video Process Complete", "======================== Video Process Complete ======================================");

             Log.e("Video Path", "Path - "+mFfmpegController.pathOuputVideo());

             Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Video Process Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             stopSelfResult(lateststartid);
             Common.ScreenshotCounter = 0;
             Common.ScreenshotTimerCounter = 0;
             /*try {
                copyFile(new FileInputStream(mFfmpegController.pathOuputVideo()), new FileOutputStream(Common.strPathForVideos));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

         }
     };
```

**Please note:**

Captured images must be in format like:

> Img00001, Img00002 .......

Because FFMPEG code expects it this way.

Fo those who didn't find R.raw.ffmpeg :
Go To : https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/res/raw/ffmpeg

Comment: What is `ffmpeg` in `R.raw.ffmpeg` ?

Comment: is it necessary to have FFmpeg binaries for different platform architecture in order to run this controller?

Comment: how to add ffmpeg in raw, and after adding its showing unknown format

Answer (score 4):

There's plenty of tools for editing videos like [INDE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials), [FFMPEG](http://bambuser.com/opensource) and etc.

INDE has so many functionality to join videos and images.

If you decide to use FFMPEG then [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662723/how-to-make-a-video-from-set-of-images-in-android-like-flipagram) provides steps for integration of this tool

Other helpful links:

[FFMPEG:Multiple Image frames + 1 Audio =1 Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463719/ffmpegmultiple-image-frames-1-audio-1-video/21304505#21304505)

[Android make animated video from list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images)

[Android ffmpeg: create video from sequnce of images using jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900215/android-ffmpeg-create-video-from-sequnce-of-images-using-jni)

[Combine an image into audio file and make a video file in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071981/combine-an-image-into-audio-file-and-make-a-video-file-in-android-programmatical)

[Video creation from series of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075042/video-creation-from-series-of-images)

[How to Build Android Applications Based on FFmpeg by An Example](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this libray

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

in this library they mention that you create movie from images(Jpeg image).

Comment: This libraries mention that it can't combine images into videos on its FAQ