# How to combine images to mp4 use ffmpeg api

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to use ffmpeg library to combine images to video, I have
 refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073336/how-to-combine-images-and-generate-a-mp4-file),but it seems to use command line direct, so how should I to do that from api? Thanks!