# How to generate video file in mp4 format from images store in sdcard in android?

Tags: java, android, javacv, android-ffmpeg

i m struggling in generating video file from collection of images that store in sdcard in specific folder in android.can any one help me to how to make this happen in android.

Comment: this may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073336/how-to-combine-images-and-generate-a-mp4-file

Comment: @Zombie thanks for help.but my task for video generation is completed successfully with javacv.